# How to read .000 file type in python for Machine Learning?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning

I have to apply Machine Learning Algorithms on a dataset. But the problem that I've been facing is loading this dataset. I've tried nanoscope library but couldn't succeed. How should I proceed with this?
The dataset can be found here :

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/eeg-mld/

Comment: Have you tried Pandas?

Answer (score 1):

These appear to just be plain text files, so you should be able to read them with `open` and `read` ([Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)), or any other appropriate tool for that matter (e.g. `pandas.read_csv` ([link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)), `csv` module ([link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)), the list goes on).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was really helpful. It worked for me :)